# How to include multiple filters in filter.includes parameter for my flink metric reporter in flink-conf.yaml?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, metrics

I want to understand the working of a generic flink metrics reporter and I am trying out the [filter.includes](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/deployment/metric_reporters/#filter-includes) parameter. How do I specify multiple filters for this option in flink-conf.yaml? The docs mention that the parameter is a `List<String>` and I verified the same by looking at tests in DefaultMetricFilterTest.java file.

I have tried the following:

1. separating filters by semicolon:

The other list parameters explicitly mention separation by semicolon. for example classloader.parent.first-patterns.default

My exact config was:

```
metric.reporters.my_reporter.filter.includes: "jobmanager:*:*";"taskmanager:*:*"
```

In this case, only the first filter is picked up and taskmanager metrics are ignored.

2. List specification in yaml.

   ```
    metric.reporters.my_reporter.filter.includes:
      - jobmanager:*:*
      - taskmanager:*:*
   ```

   Result: None of the filters are applied and all metrics, including task/operator scoped metrics are reported.
3. Specifying a list

   ```
       metric.reporters.my_reporter.filter.includes: ["jobmanager:*:*","taskmanager:*:*"]
   ```

Result: the square bracket of list is not recognized and I get an error which says "Unclosed character class near index 13 (["jobmanager)"

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Seperate filters by ';' works for me with Flink 1.16.3, relative code for parsing list type config I think is org.apache.flink.configuration.ConfigurationUtils#convertToList.

```yaml
metrics.reporter.promgateway.filter.excludes: taskmanager.Status.*:*:*;taskmanager.job.task.Shuffle.*:*:*;taskmanager.job.task:*:*;taskmanager.job.task.operator:*:*
metrics.reporter.promgateway.filter.includes: taskmanager.job.task.operator.KafkaSourceReader.KafkaConsumer:*:*;jobmanager:numRunningJobs:*
```